# R Shiny : 2 checkboxGroupInput names or values in an object

Tags: r, shiny

*
*
Hello, I'm new to R and I don't understand why my code does not work as expected. If you see where I'm wrong, please tell me.

I have an object named VAR which must take values of the checked boxes of a checkboxGroupInput named input$dynamic_provinces OR it must take values of another checkboxGroupInput named input$dynamic depending on the choices we make in the "Provinces" tab.

And I have another object named CHAMP which value is "PC" or "PROVINCE".
If we select 1 or 2 Provinces, selectionBI is created searching in "PROVINCE" variable, but if we select the 3 Provinces, selectionBI is created on the "PC" variable.

And I don't manage to give the checkboxGroupInput values to VAR, so my code returns 0. Please, try this reproducible example.

This is my Ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rgdal)
library(stringr)
library(XML)
library(reshape2)
library(plotrix)

dynamic_choices = c("Town 1"="01", "Town 2"="02", "Town 3"="03", "Town
                    4"="04", "Town 5"="05", "Town 6"="06",
                "Town 7"="07", "Town 8"="08", "Town 9"="09", "Town 
                    10"="10", "Town 11"="11", "Town 12"="12",
                "Town 13"="13", "Town 14"="14", "Town 15"="15", "Town 
                    16"="16", "Town 17"="17", "Town 18"="18",
                "Town 19"="19", "Town 20"="20")



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Test"),

   dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "Menu1",
  menuSubItem("Provinces",icon = icon("circle-o"), tabName = 
                  "provinces"),
  menuSubItem("Cities",icon = icon("spinner"), tabName = "cities"),
  menuItem(strong("Population datas"), tabName = "data_pop", icon = 
        icon("user")),
  menuSubItem("Population 1",icon = icon("users"), tabName = 
        "Population_1"))),

 dashboardBody(
   tabItems( 
     tabItem(tabName = "provinces",
          fluidRow(
            box(title = "Provinces level", width = 3, solidHeader = 
                TRUE, status = "primary",
                checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_provinces", label = "", 
                c("North","South","East")))
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "cities",
          box(title = "Cities level", width = 9, solidHeader = TRUE, 
               status = "primary",
              checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", label = "", 
               c(dynamic_choices))) # f. de box

  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "Population_1",
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 4,
                   box(title = "Features", width = NULL, solidHeader = 
                        TRUE, status = "primary",
                       DT::dataTableOutput("dfBI"))
            )
          )
  )
)
)
)
```

And this my Server.R :

```
########################## Init answers provinces 

selection = list("North"=c("Town 1"="01","Town 2"="02","Town 
                            3"="03","Town 4"="04",
                      "Town 5"="05","Town 6"="06","Town 7"="07","Town 
                             8"="08",
                      "Town 9"="09"),
             "South"=c("Town 10"="10","Town 11"="11","Town 
                        12"="12","Town 13"="13",
                     "Town 14"="14","Town 15"="15","Town 16"="16","Town 
                         17"="17"),
             "East"=c("Town 18"="18","Town 19"="19","Town 20"="20"))


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  ########################### MATCHES CHECKBOXES PROVINCES/CITIES 

 observeEvent(input$dynamic_provinces, {
    selected = c()

 for (s in input$dynamic_provinces) {
  selected = c(selected, selection[[s]])
 }

 if (is.null(selected)) {
  selected = character(0)
  VAR <- 0
 }
 updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dynamic", selected = selected)

 if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 1){(CHAMP <- "PROVINCE")
  VAR <- "input$dynamic_provinces"}

 if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 2){(CHAMP <- "PROVINCE")
  VAR <- "input$dynamic_provinces"}

 if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 3){(CHAMP <- "PC")
  VAR <- c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11",
           "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20")}

 }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

 ###################### POPULATION 1 TAB

 selectionBI <- reactive({filter(DTtest, CHAMP %in% 
                          VAR)})

 ######################## TABLE dfBI : FEATURES POPULATION 

selectionBITable <- reactive({
tmp <- selectionBI()
dfBI <- data.frame(
  Rubriques = c("Number of residents", 
                "Men", 
                "Women", 
                "Minors", 
                "Boys",
                "Girls",
                "Adults",
                "Men",
                "Women"),
  Nombre = c(
    NROW(selectionBI()),
    NROW(filter(tmp, S == "1")),
    NROW(filter(tmp, S == "2")),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18)),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18 & S == "1")),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18 & S == "2")),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17)),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17 & S == "1")),
    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17 & S == "2")))
)
dfBI
})

 output$dfBI <- renderDataTable(selectionBITable(),options = 
 list(paging = FALSE,ordering = FALSE,searching = FALSE,info = FALSE))
})
```

And an example of the DTtest data frame :

```
PC;S;AGER;PROVINCE;KAR
01;1;34;North;
01;2;32;North;
01;1;7;North;
02;1;22;North;
02;2;20;North;
03;2;75;North;
04;1;45;North;
04;2;42;North;
04;2;15;North;
05;1;67;North;
05;1;60;North;
05;1;56;North;
05;2;48;North;
06;1;25;North;01
06;2;27;North;01
06;2;35;North;01
06;1;11;North;01
06;1;42;North;02
06;2;37;North;02
06;2;13;North;02
06;1;48;North;03
06;2;43;North;03
06;1;17;North;03
06;1;15;North;03
06;2;26;North;03
07;1;36;North;04
07;2;35;North;04
07;1;10;North;04
07;1;38;North;04
07;2;35;North;04
07;2;10;North;04
07;2;27;North;05
07;2;8;North;05
07;1;25;North;05
07;2;22;North;05
07;1;31;North;06
07;2;32;North;06
07;1;7;North;06
07;1;5;North;06
07;1;68;North;06
07;2;65;North;06
08;1;72;North;
09;1;27;North;
09;2;25;North;
09;2;1;North;
10;1;43;South;
10;2;40;South;
10;1;20;South;
10;1;12;South;
11;2;86;South;
12;1;23;South;
12;2;21;South;
12;1;33;South;
12;2;32;South;
12;2;8;South;
13;1;42;South;
13;2;41;South;
13;2;17;South;
18;1;35;East
18;2;34;East
18;2;13;East
19;1;21;East
19;2;23;East
19;1;35;East
19;2;32;East
19;1;5;East
20;1;53;East
20;2;51;East
20;2;21;East
20;2;17;East
20;1;13;East
```

Please, if you see where is the problem, tell me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Take care to handle the start when there is no selection, this is not done.

This is an edit trying to include the district. I am not sure if a understood your intension correctly but hopefully this should get you started. To make thing a bit cleaner a global.R is included. Just be sure to modify global.R to read in your data set in the first line of code.

global.R

```
    # Load data
    DTtest <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    # Prepare provinces choices
    choicesProvinces <- unique(DTtest$PROVINCE)
    # Prepare cities choices
    choicesCities <- unique(DTtest$PC)
    names(choicesCities) <- paste0("Town ", choicesCities)
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)        
            shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

                    ########################### MATCHES CHECKBOXES PROVINCES/CITIES 
                    rv <- reactiveValues(CHAMP=character(), 
                                         VAR=character())

                     observeEvent(input$dynamic_provinces, {
                            selectedCities = c()
                            if (!is.null(input$dynamic_provinces)) {
                                    selectedCities = as.character(unique(DTtest[DTtest$PROVINCE %in% input$dynamic_provinces, 1]))
                            }

                            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dynamicCities", selected = selectedCities)

                            if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 1){(rv$CHAMP <- "PROVINCE")
                                    rv$VAR <- input$dynamic_provinces}

                            if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 2){(rv$CHAMP <- "PROVINCE")
                                    rv$VAR <- input$dynamic_provinces}

                            if (length(input$dynamic_provinces) == 3){(rv$CHAMP <- "PC")
                                    rv$VAR <- c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11",
                                             "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20")}

                    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

                    observeEvent(input$dynamicCities, {
                            selectedDistricts = c()
                            if (!is.null(input$dynamicCities)) {
                                    selectedDistricts = as.character(unique(DTtest[DTtest$PC %in% input$dynamicCities, 5]))
                                    filterDistrict = !is.na(selectedDistricts)
                                    selectedDistricts = selectedDistricts[filterDistrict]
                                    if (length(selectedDistricts) > 0) {
                                            names(selectedDistricts) = paste0("District ", selectedDistricts)       
                                    }

                                    print(selectedDistricts[filterDistrict])
                                    #updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dynamicDistricts", selected = selectedDistricts[filterDistrict])
                                    output$dynamicDistrictsInput <- renderUI({
                                            checkboxGroupInput("dynamicDistricts", label = "", choices = selectedDistricts, 
                                                               selected = selectedDistricts
                                            )
                                    })
                            }


                    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)



                    ###################### POPULATION 1 TAB

                    #selectionBI <- reactive({filter(DTtest, rv$CHAMP %in% 
                    #                                        rv$VAR)})

                    selectionBI <- reactive({
                            if (rv$CHAMP == "PROVINCE") {
                                 return(filter(DTtest, PROVINCE %in% rv$VAR))   
                            } 
                            if (!is.null(input$dynamicDistricts)) {
                                    return(filter(DTtest, PC %in% as.numeric(input$dynamicCities, KAR %in% as.numeric(input$dynamicDistricts))))                                  
                            }
                            return(filter(DTtest, PC %in% as.numeric(input$dynamicCities)))                                           



                    })

                    ######################## TABLE dfBI : FEATURES POPULATION 

                    selectionBITable <- reactive({

                                    tmp <- selectionBI()
                                    dfBI <- data.frame(
                                            Rubriques = c("Number of residents", 
                                                          "Men", 
                                                          "Women", 
                                                          "Minors", 
                                                          "Boys",
                                                          "Girls",
                                                          "Adults",
                                                          "Men",
                                                          "Women"),
                                            Nombre = c(
                                                    NROW(selectionBI()),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, S == "1")),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, S == "2")),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18)),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18 & S == "1")),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER < 18 & S == "2")),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17)),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17 & S == "1")),
                                                    NROW(filter(tmp, AGER > 17 & S == "2")))
                                    )        

                            dfBI
                    })

                    output$dfBI <- renderDataTable(selectionBITable(),options = 
                                                           list(paging = FALSE,ordering = FALSE,searching = FALSE,info = FALSE))
                    output$letsSee <- renderPrint({
                            str(DTtest)
                    })

            })
```

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plyr)
    library(DT)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(rgdal)
    library(stringr)
    library(XML)
    library(reshape2)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
            dashboardHeader(
                    title = "Test"),

            dashboardSidebar(
                    sidebarMenu(
                            id = "Menu1",
                            menuSubItem("Provinces",icon = icon("circle-o"), tabName = 
                                                "provinces"),
                            menuSubItem("Cities",icon = icon("spinner"), tabName = "cities"),
                            menuSubItem("Districts",icon = icon("spinner"), tabName = "districts"),
                            menuItem(strong("Population datas"), tabName = "data_pop", icon = 
                                             icon("user")),
                            menuSubItem("Population 1",icon = icon("users"), tabName = 
                                                "Population_1"))),

            dashboardBody(
                    tabItems( 
                            tabItem(tabName = "provinces",
                                    fluidRow(
                                            box(title = "Provinces level", width = 3, solidHeader = 
                                                        TRUE, status = "primary",
                                                checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_provinces", label = "", 
                                                                   c("North","South","East"))),
                                            verbatimTextOutput("test")
                                    )
                            ),
                            tabItem(tabName = "cities",
                                    box(title = "Cities level", width = 9, solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                        status = "primary",
                                        checkboxGroupInput("dynamicCities", label = "", choices = choicesCities
                                                           )) # f. de box

                            ),
                            tabItem(tabName = "districts",
                                    box(title = "District level", width = 9, solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                        status = "primary",
                                        uiOutput("dynamicDistrictsInput")
                                    )

                            ),
                            tabItem(tabName = "Population_1",
                                    fluidRow(
                                            column(width = 4,
                                                   box(title = "Features", width = NULL, solidHeader = 
                                                               TRUE, status = "primary",
                                                       DT::dataTableOutput("dfBI"))

                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: Hello Valter, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very very much one more time. Have a very nice day.

Comment: Hello Valter, I have just a question please : do you think it's possible to add one more geographic level using the same principle of code you have provided above ? For example if towns 6 and 7 have disctricts ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it mean that your data frame would have one more column to filter with or to rephrase the question how would you determine the district?

Comment: Yes, I have one more column for districts : "KAR". Thank you for replying Valter.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of this new data, and a bit an explanation how would the filtering exactly work...

Comment: Yes, I have edited the data frame with the district column "KAR". In this example, only town 06 and 07 have districts, but it's an example. I woulld like to add a new checkboxGroup for districts. The disctrict number doesn't start from "01" for each town, but only for town "06" until "03", then it goes on "04" for town "07" and ends at "06". I don't know how to do ?

Comment: Maybe concatenate "PC" and "KAR" in a new column and doing a "substr" on 2 first characters if rv$CHAMP != "PROVINCE" or a "substr" on  digits 3 and 4 if only a district is chosen in the district checkboxgroup. I don't know, I'm just a beginner but obviously, I want to things too complicated for me with R, lol.

Comment: Thank you very much Valter.

Comment: So great ! It's an excellent start, I'm going to adapt your answer to get exactly what I want. You're a king Valter, I would never have found without your help. Thank you very very much again. Have a very nice day.